# Adding foreign key constrain fails on subcriber

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I have a replicated database using SQL Server 2008. Here is what I am trying to do.

1. Create a new table  (MyNewTable)
2. Create a column in an existing Table (MyExistingTable)
3. Create a FK constraint on this column (in #2) as it points to PK to new table from #1.

However when data get replicated to subscriber, i get following error in replication monitor.

> The schema script "script for adding foreign key constraint" could not be propagated to the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201001)
>   Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147201001
>   Foreign key "MyFKConstraint" references invalid table "MyNewTable" (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1767)

This script runs fine on publisher though. Some people seem to suggest that adding foreign key constraint cannot be done in a replicated environment when its created between an existing table and a new table. This is kind of hard to buy for me although I am kind of new to SQL Server replication. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> > > Foreign key "MyFKConstraint" references invalid table "MyNewTable

Is "MyNewTable" in subscriber database?

if not can you use "NOT FOR REPLICATION" while creating FK